# Installing postgresql 9.1 with webmin?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, postgresql

I am new to webmin. I have managed to install it on a node. I explored the PostgreSQL module and installed it too. The PostgreSQL version is 8.4.8. ([released](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-8-4-8.html) on 2011-04-18, which is recent).

I am interested in using PostgreSQL 9.1. My questions are:

1. Is it possible to install 9.1 with webmin yet? If yes, how?
2. If answer to 1. is no, should I just be patient, knowing that 9.1 has been released very recently and that it will be integrated into webmin soon?
3. Assuming that I start working with 8.4.8, will PostgreSQL or Webmin help with the migration from 8.4.8 to 9.1?

I could not find definitive answers with my googling. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try here: http://davidghedini.blogspot.com/2010/10/install-postgresql-9-on-centos.html